# Word Match Search with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

what would be the best way to do a word match search in PL/SQL?

E.g. for the string "*BROUGHTONS OF CHELTENHAM LIMITED*"

"BROUGHTONS LIMITED" is a **match**

"OF LIMITED" is a **match**

"CHELTENHAM BROUGHTONS" is a **match**

"BROUG" is a **non-match**

Comment: As in the Bentley dealer? Small world ;) Anyway, to answer your question vaguely, you would need to tokenise the search string and then query against the tokens... [I've done something similar for personal names](http://xoph.co/20111007/building-a-better-search-engine/), you could adapt this to your needs relatively easily. If you want better advice, have a go and come back with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Oracle Text index. This will allow you to issue powerful CONTAINS queries.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/quicktour.htm

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rather crude approach, but should do what you are asking.  As Xophmeister noted, you probably need to tokenize each string and then search the tokens (since you want to match out of order, doing a simple "like %tokenA%tokenB%tokenC%" won't work).

Also, this doesn't even touch all the issues around phonetics, soundex, etc.  But again, not what you asked.  This also doesn't touch performance or scaling issues, and would probably only be acceptable for a small set of data.

So, first we need a split function:

```
create or replace 
function fn_split(i_string in varchar2, i_delimiter in varchar2 default ',', b_dedup_tokens in number default 0)
return sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
as
  l_tab sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll;
begin
  select regexp_substr(i_string,'[^' || i_delimiter || ']+', 1, level)
  bulk collect into l_tab
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(i_string, '[^' || i_delimiter || ']+', 1, level) is not null
  order by level;

  if (b_dedup_tokens > 0) then
    return l_tab multiset union distinct l_tab;
  end if;
  return l_tab;
end;
```

Now we can use it to inspect strings for specific tokens.  Here I'm searching for 3 tokens (John Q Public) from a sample set of data

```
with test_data as (
  select 1 as id, 'John Q Public' as full_name from dual
  union
  select 2 as id, 'John John Smith' as full_name from dual
  union
  select 3 as id,'Sally Smith' from dual
  union
  select 4 as id, 'Mr John B B Q Public' from dual
  union
  select 5 as id, 'A Public John' from dual
)
select d.id, d.full_name, count(1) as hits
from test_data d, table(fn_split(full_name, ' ', 1))
-- should have at least 1 of these tokens
where column_value in ('John', 'Q', 'Public')
group by d.id, d.full_name
-- can also restrict results to those with at least x token hits
having count(1) >= 2
-- most hits at top of results
order by count(1) desc, id asc
```

Output:

```
"ID"    "FULL_NAME" "HITS"
1   "John Q Public" 3
4   "Mr John B B Q Public"  3
5   "A Public John" 2
```

You can also add "upper" to make case insensitive, etc.